# My domain gives 301 moved permanently, eventually loads or doesn't load my Apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an Apache server, where the root website directory is located at **/var/www/html/**. I have a domain I purchased on GoDaddy that contains an @ A record which points to my home IP Address where my server is located. On the server end, I have a private folder inside my website directory protected correctly with a username and password, as you'll see in my server configuration. I noticed that when I go to my domain with Chrome, sometimes it will load instantly, and other times (according to the Google Chrome Developer Network Console) I will keep getting a "301 Moved Permanently" status code from my server. Is there something I am overlooking?

My website conf file (replaced with example.com for temporary privacy):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html 

    <Directory "/var/www/html/private">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
    
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And here is the .htaccess file located at the root of my website, which might help:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What are the URL(s) being redirected from/to? (According to Chrome.) The only redirect you've posted is in your `.htaccess` file. However, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ has an erroneous slash prefix, so will never match - so isn't actually doing anything!?

Comment: I originally didn't have a .htaccess file, I just had my configuration file so I saw that from somewhere and tried it with no luck. Of course, it magically works now, but I foresee it will stop working. All the entries in chrome all say [http://example.com](http://exmaple.com). It didn't seem to go back and forth between two different places for example.

Comment: Update: Back to a 301 Moved Permanently (too many redirects)

Comment: There's nothing in what you've posted that could even hint as to why you are seeing an "occasional" 301 redirect-loop. You've only posted the vHost for port 80, are you not using HTTPS? What is the URL being requested?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... [here's](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AifeA1WVOH1b6Xz_oYs3yJT7hTIZ) what the chrome console shows when I get too many redirects. Other times my website will load with no issues. I am as confused as you are. Let me know if you need me to show you something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a working solution. It wasn't the server's fault, it was the way I set up GoDaddy. Inside your domain's DNS settings, have the server permanently redirect to your public IP address. Ensure it is a masked redirection so that your domain stays in the web address bar.

Comment: "Ensure it is a masked redirection" - You shouldn't be setting up any kind of "redirection" at the DNS provider? The point of configuring an `A` record is so that a redirect is not required. (?)

Comment: There was an A record that I couldn't delete in GoDaddy, so the A record would go there instead of my IP. I just used a masked redirection to get around this.